# How to display code inside a block

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, codeblocks

how can i display code inside blocks like stackoverflow does this:

```
<p> <strong> strong text <em> strong and emphasised text </em> </strong> <em> just emphasised text </em> </p>
```

note: i have all the text wrapped around a div and retrieved from a database

thanks

Comment: **Hint:** View the source code of [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562211/how-to-display-code-inside-a-block).

Comment: @rfausak, linking to W3Schools is frowned upon here... an answer might receive down-votes for that reason alone.  See [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Disregard previous comment, see [HTML entities](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/html-entity-chart.shtml) as [posted by Sparky672](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562211/how-to-display-code-inside-a-block/7562248#7562248)

Comment: do you mean like a this syntax highlighter?: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/
I use it and it works great.

Comment: @Sparky672: I don't know if I'd say linking to W3Schools is frowned upon. Yes, there are a lot of problems and errors within the site, but it's still a good resource. I learned a lot from there when I first started.

Comment: @fudgey, just conveying my opinion of how I see most people here react to those links. They're certainly not celebrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characters making up the HTML code are converted into their corresponding [HTML entities](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/html-entity-chart.shtml)...

```
<pre>
  <code>
    &lt;p&gt; &lt;strong&gt; strong text &lt;em&gt; strong and emphasised text &lt;/em&gt; &lt;/strong&gt; &lt;em&gt; just emphasised text &lt;/em&gt; &lt;/p&gt;
  </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: but how do i only replace the code within the pre without replacing pre it self

Comment: That's not an issue because the `<pre><code>` and `</code></pre>` are not part of the code in your database... it's the HTML on the page where you are displaying the block.

Comment: Actually the text contains both text and `<pre></pre>` so it's basically a `<div>some text <pre>some code</pre> some text</div>`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're wanting... but if you want to display the "`<pre>`" as text, then you have to convert it, if you want the `<pre>` to behave like html code, then you skip the `<pre>`'s when you parse.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grab code, then convert it for viewing, just replace the `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`. Here is a simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/356SR/) doing just that.

```
var html = $('#html').html(),
    code = $.trim(html); // remove leading & trailing carriage returns

// replace angled brackets
code = code.replace(/[<>]/g, function(m){
        return {
            '<' : '&lt;',
            '>' : '&gt;'
        }[m];
    });

$('pre').html(code);
```